# vba index match error run time error '424' Object required

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have this code but can't seems to solve the problem,

```
Sub IndMat()
Dim wh1 As Worksheet
Dim wh2 As Worksheet
Set wh1 = Sheets("SAS")
Set wh2 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim y As VariantDim x As LongDim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
lr1 = wh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = wh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wh2.Range("a2:a25")    
Set rng2 = wh2.Range("b2:b25")
For i = 2 To lr1 
y = application.Index(rng1, Application.Match(wh1.Cells(i, 5), rng2, 0))
Next i 
End Sub
```

The error exposes when running
`y = application.Index(rng1, Application.Match(wh1.Cells(i, 5), rng2, 0))`

Comment: `applciation` is a typo in your code or only in this question? Are you using `Option Explicit` ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo in the code printed above not in the VBA code  so the porblem still exist.

Comment: Can you update your question so it shows *exactly* the code you have? There are other lines that doesn't seem to be correct, eg `Dim y As VariantDim x As LongDim lr1 As Long`

Comment: My mistake, corrected and it worked! :) .Thanks.,

Comment: If I would like to print the result in a specif range of cells i.e to the right of cell matched. would i use debug.print or is there a better way to do this?